# What is the motivation to define lower (upper) semicontinuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $X$ be a metric space. A function $f \colon X \mapsto \mathbb{R} \cup\lbrace -\infty, \infty  \rbrace  $ is lower semicontinuous at a point $x_{0}$, if $$ \liminf \limits_{x \rightarrow x_{0}} f(x) \ge f(x_{0}). $$ Similarly, we can define upper semicontinuous functions. But I want to know, what is the motivation for defining these functions. Do, these functions arises in some real life applications or make sense only theoretically.

Comment: Have a look at the references on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity